# How to display library permissions to members?

Tags: 2007, permissions, document-library, security

Working on a SP2007 implementation that has a large number of document libraries with custom permissions set, and they have a requirement to give better visibility of who has access to each library. Struggling to find a good way to display the permissions on the library page, as the Site Users part only has options to show users/groups who have permissions at the site level, or to show users within a specified group.

The latter option gets us mostly there, but listing individual users can result in a long scrolling list that is nasty even when limiting the web part size. Preference would be to actually show those groups that have permissions on the library, but I haven't found even a custom part that does this for a library yet.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I suspect a cleaner way would be to move towards Document Workspaces, which have their People And Groups pages available to members to inspect, while libraries don't seem to have an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPServices to iterate the permissions client side, assuming the current user has permission to see them.